# Set Azure DevOps field to read only after updating it

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to update a field to the current users name when a Boolean field switches to true. Then I want the field to be read only, so it shows that user at all times from then on.

I can set the field fine, but when I add the logic to do read only it just sets the empty field to read only without updating it.

Is this possible?

I've tried adding a hidden field to update, then copy that value to the original field before setting to read only, but I get the same result.

I only need it to happen upon the initial field change, so not bothered about ever updating it again.

Thanks!

[Setting the value of "Reviewed by" when a Boolean is set to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s290S.png)

[Setting to read only when field is updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7ZkM.png)

[Blank read only field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukWVA.png)

Comment: Hi @Wes D, Have you got a chance to check my workaround below? If the information may resolve your query in this thread, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), which may help others encountering similar issues. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @WesD, May I know if you have tested the workaround below? Would you accept the answer which may benefit other community members with similar concerns? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I can reproduce the same. It appears impossible to update and make the **same** field read-only within 1 **single** editing operation, since we can notice the failure when setting up the rule below saying `: The action ReadOnly cannot be used with the action Copy when applied to the same field under the same conditions.` Even though, we used different rules with different conditions, I found it impossbile for the rules to take effect on the same field within 1 single editing operation and I believe the failures share the same logic.
[image]

For this, I figured out a workaround, which was to sperate the `update` and `make read-only` actions into 2 editing operations. Here are the steps for your reference.

1. For the work item rule `Read0only Peer Reviewed`, I used another custom Boolean field `Lock` to determine if the field `Peer Reviewed by` should be made read-only;
   [image]
2. In the first editing operation onto my work item, I set the `Peer Reviewed` field as `true` and the `Peer Reviewed by` field was populated; then I clicked on the `Save` button;
   [image]
3. In the second editing operation, I set the filed `Lock` to be `true`, which made the field `Peer Reviewed by` to be read-only; then I clicked on the `Save` button again.
   [image]

Still, it is simply a workaround as I can understand it is somehow bothering to edit the work item multiple times. You may also consider [creating a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?cspace=21&entry=suggestion) to report this limitation. That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Hope the idea could be helpful.